# local storage not working on FullCalendar first load

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am trying to make my full calendar code remember the previous date and then load that automatically on next refresh. The code I have works well on everything except the first load of the page. When I load the page for the first time, it will give an error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getUTCFullYear')". If I delete the line `initialDate : new Date(localStorage.fullCalendarDefaultDate),` then the page will load correctly, and if I add that line back in then refresh the page, it will work correctly and remember the last month view.

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
timeZone: 'UTC',
locale:'en',
 headerToolbar: {
  left: 'prev,next today',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay',     
  //right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay' Includes time views when we add them
},
initialDate : new Date(localStorage.fullCalendarDefaultDate),
events: 'loadMasterDates.php',
editable:true,
datesSet: function(dateInfo) 
{
    var date = new Date(dateInfo.view.currentStart);
    localStorage.fullCalendarDefaultDate = date.toISOString();
}
)}
```

I tried then to add this to the top of the code but it then just seemed to keep overwriting the localStorage variable and would keep loading today's date on refresh.

```
    if(typeof initialDate ==='undefined'){
     localStorage.fullCalendarDefaultDate = new Date;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`if(typeof initialDate ==='undefined'){` makes no sense. At no point does your code try to define a global variable called `initialDate`

I think what you need to do is try to read the localStorage value, and if that fails, either don't set the fullCalendar `initialDate` option, or just set it to today's date.

Something like this should work:

```
var storedDate = localStorage.fullCalendarDefaultDate;

if (typeof storedDate !== 'undefined') calDate = new Date(localStorage.fullCalendarDefaultDate);
else calDate = new Date();

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  timeZone: 'UTC',
  locale: 'en',
  headerToolbar: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay',
    //right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay' Includes time views when we add them
  },
  initialDate: calDate,
  events: 'loadMasterDates.php',
  editable: true,
  datesSet: function(dateInfo) {
    var date = new Date(dateInfo.view.currentStart);
    localStorage.fullCalendarDefaultDate = date.toISOString();
  }
})
```